# Drupal 8 Twig removes all style tags from variable during rendering

Tags: drupal, twig

How to retain all content of a variable which was added during preprocess_page.

e.g. style tags also needs to be added while variable rendering in twig files.

Comment: Please add some code with the problem

Comment: We can't bring to you some help without more details, code , purpose and context. Be more accurate and will bring to you an accurate answer

Comment: Answered based on my requirement with different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MaisexpertBlock extends BlockBase {
    public function build() {
        return array(
            //'#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
            '#template' => '{{ somecontent | raw }}',
            '#context' => array('somecontent' => 'Your content with <html></html> code'),
        );
    }
}
```